# Fisher Score : Feature Selection

Tags: r, feature-selection

```
               x             y       z     class
1     7.522090573  0.0947621201 0.9192131     1
2     8.377329857  0.9239476238 1.0268833     1
3    10.410897014  2.0579569672 1.0897411     1
4    10.010138206 -0.3497298457 0.9102357     1
5     9.491516152  1.8705499267 1.0703253     1
6     7.786660913 -0.4463353869 1.0122466     2
7     5.780161404  1.1631841759 0.9662667     2
8     7.554845700  1.9681194910 1.0456867     2
9     6.922824035 -0.2138662050 0.9436512     2
10   10.135732626  1.8476083237 0.9615607     2
11    6.353756197  0.5373878078 0.9589364     3
12    6.287035692 -0.8354052695 0.9137127     3
13    9.407254887  3.2034614134 1.0970670     3
14    5.354989965  0.4835880495 1.0722515     3
15    6.959790979 -1.5402692379 1.0640177     3
```

My data is in this form I want to compute the **Fisher Score** of each feature of one class at a time. Can anyone suggest me how to implement in R?

Comment: `by` function should be ideal. The pseudo code would look like this: `by(mydata, mydata$class, fisher.score.fun)`